# JSON Formatting Multilanguage Sections Displayname

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

Can you please tell me if it's possible to have Body sections in the JSON list formatting as multilingual?

If yes, how to please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible using JSON formatting capabilities in SharePoint.

> Unlike the header and the footer, body configuration **only allows defining one or more sections** and adding one or more columns into each of those sections.

Body configuration does not support advance JSON customizations like header/footer (or column/view formatting in list views).

**Source**: [Configure custom body with one or more sections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-body-with-one-or-more-sections)

You may need to customize the list form using Power Apps to make list form multilingual.